# what ORM use to get access to the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, mybatis

The question is that I don't understand how orms get access to the database. With JDBC we create connection, write statements and get result. But orm?

I mean - what does Mybatis or Hibernate or other orms use to get access to the database and run queries? 
Implementation of JPA? JDBC? What is under the their hoods? They use database drivers?

I'm very curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC is a low level mechanism for interacting with the database, but it's the base of any Java database interaction. The JDBC doesn't offer any transaction management integration, since it only allows you to implement local transactions (based on the current database connection commit/rollback). It's also verbose and on large enterpise applications, with thousand of queries, it's simply pain to add a new column to a base table as you'd have to update zillions of existing queries.

Beside the object to relational mapping ability, ORM tools come with many other useful features:

1. optimistic locking on complex entity trees
2. polymorphic queries
3. local and XA transaction management integration
4. schema generation
5. database independent basic querying and DML

But you don't have to use only the ORM tool. In fact this is an anti-pattern on large applications.

You usually mix Hibernate with native querying, or [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) to benefit from database specific features (window functions, common table expressions, etc)

The best approach is to use a [data layer stack](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-data-knowledge-stack/) approach, where you pick and mix the best of Hibernate/JDBC/JOOQ.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you like my answers.

Answer (score 2):

JPA implementations like Hibernate and EclipseLink use JDBC for connection and SQL execution, which in turn uses a DB driver.

It is one of the purposes of the JPA specification - to abstract away the DB connection ans SQL generation and execution from your application code.

Comment: So basically JDBC is everywhere?

Comment: Yes - the JDBC details that are considered nonessential by JPA are hidden, but they still do their job (and sometimes leak problems).